# Conditional convergence of the Hadamard product

Tags: riemann-zeta, hadamard-product, conditional-convergence

The product
$$\prod_\rho \left(1-\frac{s}{\rho}\right)$$
where $\rho$ ranges over all zeros of the Riemann zeta function is often referred to as the Hadamard product (because its convergence was first shown by Hadamard). It is often mentioned that the convergence is only conditional, and it can only be proven if we pair a zero $\rho$ with its symmetrical one $1-\rho$, so that the product actually becomes
$$\prod_{\rm Im (\rho)\gt 0}\left(1-\frac{s(1-s)}{\rho(1-\rho}\right).$$
But I cannot find an actual proof that the convergence $\bf{is}$ conditional, that is,
the product will diverge with a different order, or it will converge to different values. So I wonder if this is something unproven, or if there is a proof of it.

Comment: This follows by general  theory as $\sum 1/|\rho|$ is infinite (for this essentially the only things needed are the theory of entire functions  order and type, the functional  equation and Stirling as they imply $\xi$ is entire, order 1 maximal type and for those the above divergence of the sum of absolute values of the roots reciprocals is part of the theory ) and that is equivalent  by taking logarithms and usual logarithm approximation to the divergence of the product $\Pi (1-1/|\rho|)$; it is not hard to regroup the roots to get a divergent product for example

Comment: It's possible to show that $\sum_{|\rho|\le T}1/|\rho|$ grows like $(\log T)^2$, so the product is not absolutely convergent.